# TypeError: Date.prototype.Method is not a function - method suddenly not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function called Date.prototype.addDays. It doesn't really matter what it does, but just in case:

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
}
```

I wasn't having any issues at all, and then today I'm seeing this error:

```
TypeError: matchDate.addDays is not a function
```

I went through all the issues I could think of but can't figure it out. Here is where the method is being called, and some console.logs to show the relevant variables:

```
let matchDate = new Date(value.date)
console.log(matchDate);
console.log(value.date);
console.log((matchDate instanceof Date))
let activeDate = matchDate.addDays(dayOfTheWeek + 1);
```

And here is the output:

```
2018-04-10T11:33:20.000Z
1523360000000
true
/Users/Mariano/Documents/ML/nodetest/main_process.js:88
    let activeDate = matchDate.addDays(dayOfTheWeek + 1);
                               ^

TypeError: matchDate.addDays is not a function
```

Any thoughts?

```js
    Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
        var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
        return date;
    }

    var matchDate = new Date();
    console.log(matchDate);
    console.log((matchDate instanceof Date))
    let activeDate = matchDate.addDays(1);
    console.log("active date is " + activeDate);
```

As you can see here, the code works on Chrome, so not sure why its not working on Node. Any thoughts as to what I can do to troubleshoot?

Comment: Your code works.

Comment: it works in chrome console

Comment: Obligatory note: don't ever do this (add to builtin prototypes).

Comment: Remove this "value.date" and as Jared said, don't add to builtin proto!

Comment: value.date is where the date is coming from. You can see in the console that its parsing it correctly into a js date object.

Comment: @MarianoMolina as you can tell from the snippet added to your question, your code works. If you cannot explain further, the question will eventually be closed.

Comment: Also, it makes sense that it works in the Chrome console. Like I said, it was working fine until today. Which is why I'm stumped as to why this is returning an error. Any thoughts as to what I can try?

Comment: Obviously, something changed today. Just as obviously, we don't know what changed in your environment. Maybe you updated Node.js. Maybe an npm package was added that removes all extensions to built-in object prototypes as a form of defense. Maybe a colleague decided to remove it themselves and not tell you.

Comment: I don't know that it's obvious that knowbody can think of a likely thing that could have caused it and could help. Clearly nobody has yet, but that doesn't mean its obvious and therefore not worth asking.

Comment: same error occurred in react-native, can please help